# Get duplicate characters count in a string

Tags: javascript, string

Can anyone help me to get the count of repeated characters in a given string in javascript.

For example,

```
"abccdef" -> 1 (Only "c" repeated)

"Indivisibilities" -> 2 ("i" and "s" repeated)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. What we can do is turn the string to lower case using `String.toLowerCase`, and then split on `""`, so we get an array of characters.

We will then sort it with `Array.sort`. After it has been sorted, we will join it using `Array.join`.
We can then make use of the regex `/(.)\1+/g` which essentially means match a letter and subsequent letters if it's the same.

When we use `String.match` with the stated regex, we will get an Array, whose length is the answer. Also used some `try...catch` to return `0` in case match returns `null` and results in `TypeError`.

```
function howManyRepeated(str){
   try{ return str.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g).length; }
   catch(e){ return 0; } // if TypeError
}
console.log(howManyRepeated("Indivisibilities")); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I passed "abcdef", it should return 0, but it is showing an error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: @NaveenKrishna now it should work.

Comment: Wow excellent man, it works! Simple and great answer.

Comment: @NaveenKrishna glad to have helped you. I answered this because it was kinda interesting. It would be better on your part to post your try in the question. Any glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 18):

You can use like this

```
function getFrequency(string) {
var freq = {};
for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
    var character = string.charAt(i);
    if (freq[character]) {
       freq[character]++;
    } else {
       freq[character] = 1;
    }
}

return freq;
};

getFrequency('Indivisibilities');
```

Comment: Cool approach! Thanks!

Comment: we can add string.lowercase so that we get the character count with same character in either upper or lowercase

Comment: This one is faster than the one of Amit Joki.